# What package do I need to install to get video-previews in Debian's ranger?

Tags: debian, python3, ranger

What package does Ranger require to generate video-image previews in Debian? I'm using the `ranger` from `apt` and when I try to view a video's thumbnail I get,

```
Image previews in kitty require PIL (pillow)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Debian you'll need `python3-pil`, which actually provides `pillow` and the `pil` executable,

```
sudo apt install python3-pil
```

Then follow the instructions here,

- https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Video-Previews